# error retrieving information from server [df-dic-02] in android

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

**I am doing in-app purchases first time. So please Guide me some good solution. I tried to delete and add playstore account clearing data etc. but nothing worked for me. So please give some good suggestions. Here is my problem.**

I'm working with in-app purchase using third party API [link][1]

[1]: https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3 but when i click on purchases, google play show this dialog error(error retrieving information from server [df-dic-02]). here is the code i am using

```html
public class Launcher extends Activity
        implements BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler{ 


bp = new BillingProcessor(this,license_key, this);

  @Override
    public void onBillingInitialized() {
        /*
         * Called when BillingProcessor was initialized and it's ready to purchase
         */
    }

    @Override
    public void onProductPurchased(String productId, TransactionDetails details) {
        /*
         * Called when requested PRODUCT ID was successfully purchased
         */
    }

    @Override
    public void onBillingError(int errorCode, Throwable error) {
        /*
         * Called when some error occurred. See Constants class for more details
         *
         * Note - this includes handling the case where the user canceled the buy dialog:
         * errorCode = Constants.BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_USER_CANCELED
         */
    }

    @Override
    public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {
        /*
         * Called when purchase history was restored and the list of all owned PRODUCT ID's
         * was loaded from Google Play
         */
    }

  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(
            final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        if (!bp.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data))
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue was bugging me until I realised I miss typed the product ID.
You may wanna check your's also.

I am using Google's dummy product ID's

```
"android.test.purchased"
```

And the call

```
billingProcessor.purchase(this, "android.test.purchased");
```

This call should work and give you a normal dummy response from the Play Store